# Align Numbers in tabularx with standard deviation

Tags: align, tabularx, columns

I'm trying to make this table with numbers and standard deviation, how can I aligns the numbers properly?
The spacing between numbers and st.dev is too high and the numbers are not aligned to the point.

Thanks to all for support!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath} % Advanced math typesetting
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Unicode support (Umlauts etc.)
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Change hyphenation rules
\usepackage{hyperref} % Add a link to your document
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Add pictures to your document
\usepackage{listings} % Source code formatting and highlighting
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx} % for typesetting scientific units

\DeclareSIUnit\tex{TEX}
\DeclareSIUnit\ends{ends}
\DeclareSIUnit\rpm{rpm}
\DeclareSIUnit\wtp{wt\%}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 

\begin{document}    

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l YYYYY @{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Length}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Width}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Thickness}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-6}
\textbf{Test} & [\si{\mm}] & \multicolumn{2}{c}{[\si{\mm}]} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{[\si{\mm}]} \\
\midrule
\textbf{Quasi-Static \& Fatigue}& $\approx$ \num{200} & \num{24.90} & $\pm$ \num{0.20} & \num{1.95} & $\pm$ \num{0.07} \\
\textbf{Short Beam}             & $\approx$ \num{20}  & \num{4.99}  & $\pm$ \num{0.05} & \num{2.00} & $\pm$ \num{0.07} \\
\textbf{Impact}                 & $\approx$ \num{65}  & \num{13.48} & $\pm$ \num{0.21} & \num{1.95} & $\pm$ \num{0.11} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Measured dimension with standard deviation of specimens.}\label{tab:spec_meas}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: How il looks now]
How it looks now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get table alignment using `siunitx`, do *not* put the numbers inside `\num` but just straight inside an `S`-type column. Here, I'd probably go for something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\begin{tabular}
  {@{} 
    l
    >{\approx}S[table-format = \approx3]
    S[table-format = 2.2(2)]
    S[table-format = 1.2(2)]
  @{}}
  \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Dimensions/\si{mm}} \\
    &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Length} & {Width} & {Thickness} \\
  \midrule
    Quasi-static \& fatigue & 200 & 24.90(20) & 1.95(7)  \\
    Short beam              &  20 &  4.99(5)  & 2.00(7)  \\
    Impact                  &  65 & 13.48(21) & 1.95(11) \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

(I've combined the units into one place as the repeats seems superfluous, but that's of course down to you.) Notice that I've put the `\approx` into the table header, so for the `Length` heading I need a `\multicolumn` to avoid a stray one!

Comment: Off-topic, but (for example) `24.90(20)` (`24.90 ± 20`) has a meaningless last digit: `24.9(2)` would be more realistic.

Comment: thanks, I have to put them because the precision of the instrument is 0.01

Comment: Does this work with `tabularx` ?

Comment: @AndreaBetti The underlying column building is the same in `tabular` and `tabularx` (and other stuff): `siunitx` doesn't rely on anything 'special' so it should just work. (I'm not a fan of overly-broad tables and you've no `p`-type columns, so `tabular` seemed appropriate here.)